# UTF-8 encoding loads as ISO-8859-1 from Spring server

Tags: spring, github, utf-8, visual-studio-code, iso-8859-1

I'm working on SPA.

In `<head>` I have:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Working in VS Code (which shows that files are also encoded in UTF-8.
Next step - uploading to GitHub - files over there shows UTF-8.

Then is Jenkins that deploys to Spring server (based on Tomcat).
When I open site from localhost it's UTF-8 (on left), but when from server it's ISO-8859-1

[image]

When someone edits files in GitHub (website) directly and re-save the special characters (TM), the special characters will look correct (even thought the page still is served as ISO-8859-1).
Where is the cause of it? 
1. On my machine (Windows 10)? VSC?
2. On my git configuration?
3. Jenkins
4. Server?

If it's server side I will pass answer to our BE/dev-ops person.

Comment: Trademark (`™`) is not part of ISO-8859-1. Is it possible that the server is lying about the charset? Is it actually serving UTF-8?

Comment: @georgeawg  In my localhost TM is displaying fine, but in server its showing: â„¢.
I just found that in code I have also TM, but in other place I have &trade; and this one is fine in local and server, so maybe it's my fault after all. Maybe this TM was copied from copy somewhere (word doc,...). Thanks for directing me into this conclusion.

Comment: UTF-8 for ™ is `0xE2, 0x84, 0xA2` which in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout) would render as `â¢`. `0x84` is not a visible character in ISO-8859-1 but is `„` (U-201E) in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set).

Comment: You may want to read: https://www.w3.org/International/tests/repository/html5/the-input-byte-stream/results-basics#precedence  BOM will take precedence of headers. Maybe your files have BOM.

Answer (score 0):

I found that previous developer sometimes copied content from Word Doc straight into HTML templates. Characters like trademark, quotes (single or double)... shows on localhost on Windows machine, but on linux-based server they display wrong. So I had to find all of these MS Word characters and replace them with plain text.

I someone will face similar problem, this might be the cause.

Thanks for all comments, they helped me to find above solution.